# Разбить треугольники и точки на пары для которых расстояние от точки до плоскости треугольника найменьшее

Tags: c

Заданы три точки и координаты трех треугольников в пространстве. Разбить их на пары (точка - треугольник), для которых расстояние от точки до плоскости треугольника наименьшая.

Есть определение расстояний и запись их в двумерный массив, строка - треугольник столбцы - соответствующее расстояние до точки.
Нужен просто вывод типа: Точка 1 имеет самое короткое расстояние до плоскости треугольника 3

```
    int main(void) {
        float tr[3][9], distances[3][3], points[3][3];
        float pointx, pointy, pointz, tAx, tAy, tAz, tBx, tBy, tBz, tCx, tCy, tCz;
        float A, B, C, D, min = 0;
        int i, j, index;

        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            printf("Enter the coordinates of %d point:", i + 1);
            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                scanf("%f", &points[i][j]);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            printf("Enter the coordinates of %d triangle:", i + 1);
            for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                scanf("%f", &tr[i][j]);
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            tAx = tr[i][0], tAy = tr[i][1], tAz = tr[i][2], tBx = tr[i][3], tBy = tr[i][4], tBz = tr[i][5], tCx = tr[i][6], tCy = tr[i][7], tCz = tr[i][8];
            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                pointx = points[j][0], pointy = points[j][1], pointz = points[j][2];

                A = tAy * (tBz - tCz) + tBy * (tCz - tAz) + tCy * (tAz - tBz);
                B = tAx * (tCz - tBz) + tBx * (tAz - tCz) + tCx * (tBz - tAz);
                C = tAx * (tBy - tCy) + tBx * (tCy - tAy) + tCx * (tAy - tBy);
                D = -A * tAx - B * tAy - C * tAz;

                if (A == 0 && B == 0 && C == 0) {
                    printf("\nCannot create a plane equation for given points. Verify that the data entered is correct.\n");
                    return -1;
                } else
                    distances[i][j] =
                            fabs(A * pointx + B * pointy + C * pointz + D) / sqrt(pow(A, 2) + pow(B, 2) + pow(C, 2));;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Это вопрос тут уже не раз пролетал. По-прежнему не ясно что делать, если один и тот же треугольник является ближайшим для нескольких точек. Как тут разбивать на пары?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void SplitInPairs(double distances[3][3]) {
    double min;
    int i, j, l;
    int indexi = 1, indexj = 1;

    for (l = 0; l < 3; l++) {
        min = 999999;
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (distances[i][j] < min && distances[i][j] != 0) {
                    min = distances[i][j];
                    indexi = i, indexj = j;
                }
            }
        }

        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            distances[indexi][j] = 0;
            distances[j][indexj] = 0;
        }

        printf("The point %d has the shortest distance to the %d triangle - %.2lf\n", indexi + 1, indexj + 1, min);
    }
}
```